# android speech-to-text - get the first word of a recording

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm creating a reminder app, and I want to add an option for the user to record himself saying the reminder in form of "day - event" (it's more than that, but that's enough for now). For instance, for a friend's birthday party on Friday the average user would record himself saying "Friday - John's birthday party".

I would like to recognize the first word (or two words) of the recording, and save it as an offer to the name of the reminder. Is there any possibility to do that using voice recognition of Android?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the difference with recognizing the whole recording?

Answer (score 1):

The Android speech-to-text API allows you to convert audio into the corresponding string (e.g. "Friday John's birthday party"). How you parse this string (e.g. to obtain a structure containing the name of the day and the description of the event) is up to you and has to be done after the speech recognition. Android does not provide a natural language parsing/understanding functionality via the API.